# SharePoint 2010 Service Application Proxy & My Site Settings

Tags: my-site, claims-based-auth

I have a SharePoint 2010 site configured with **Claims based FBA**. I have also made **My Site** work with FBA.

**My question is:**

In 2007 I would create a separate **SSP for FBA-based My Site** and set all configuration there. As SharePoint 2010 supports **Service Application Proxy** how can I isolate FBA based My Site and other AD sites?

While I was able to select the required services for My Site using **Configure service application associations**  link in Central Admin, all changes I make in My Site settings reflect for both FBA & AD based application.

How do I isolate My Site changes ?? I wanted to have different configuration for each of the My Sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two User Profile Service Applications, one for AD, one for FBA.

Go to the web application management:

http://centraladmin/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx

Select the web application you want to associate with the FBA my site

Select Service Connections from the ribbon

Change the group to [custom]

Check the FBA User Profile Service Application, uncheck the AD one.